# Any in-built html template packager from microsoft

Tags: razor, asp.net-core, razorengine

Razorengine has been used as runtime html packager but seemingly the maintenance and support has been stopped for a year.

I have looked into a few and currently Scriban seems to be the right fit.
However before putting this into the solution, I want to make sure if Microsoft does not have their own library instead of no-guarantee in maintenance 3rd party ones.

or can I only make the minimal necessary features from razor work just to achieve creating html runtime using razor binding? For example, by adding a few references..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to create a template service based on the `ASP.NET Core` `RazorEngine` you can do get all needed services via `DI`:

```
public TemplateService(IRazorViewEngine viewEngine, IServiceProvider serviceProvider, ITempDataProvider tempDataProvider)
{
    _viewEngine = viewEngine;
    _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
    _tempDataProvider = tempDataProvider;
}
```

Register in `DI` in your `Startup` class:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // ...
    services.AddScoped<ITemplateService, TemplateService>();
    // ...
}
```

And then you can get access to `ITemplateService` by enjecting it to constructor of your `Controller` class or other service. And use `Views` and `ViewModels` to generate `HTML` using `RenderTemplateAsync` method See the [implementation details here](https://gist.github.com/wmeints/c547209b69128e4ee537cb8f35c3a6dc):

```
public async Task<string> RenderTemplateAsync<TViewModel>(string viewFilename, TViewModel viewModel)
{ 
    // ... see the details by the link above
}
```

So the call in `Controller` might look like this:

```
var htmlContent = await _templateService.RenderTemplateAsync(
    "Email/MyEmailTemplate",
    new MyEmailTemplateModel
    {
        ToFullName = "Dmitry Pavlov",
        Link = "https://stackoverflow.com/users/804385/dmitry-pavlov",
        SenderName = "Software in healthcare / medical device",
        CustomText = "Thanks for the tip! I have got it now. Appreciate your help!"
    });
```

This `HTML` text will the output of rendered `View` with the model bound to `Razor` placeholders like @Model.ToFullName in this `View`. I guess you will use some layout for the template view (I would recommend to embed all needed `CSS` styles into it - actually you can create special `_EmailTemplateLayout` file with the common `HTML` markup and specify this as `Layout` for all your email templates).

Comment: Thanks for the help.  Can you give me a little more idea?  I am not very familiar with Razor.  I believe my current VS project has Microsoft.AspNet.Razor however it was never configured as MVC project, rather more like a WEB API project. In that case what other configurations do I need to make it working together with above code?

Comment: Can you please show example how to add this service to the existing project?

Comment: You need to register template service in `DI` in your `Startup.ConfigureServices` method like this: 
services.AddScoped<ITemplateService, TemplateService>(); 
Then you can get access to `ITemplateService` via DI injection via controller constructor or other service constructor